# datatables checkbox to toggle WHERE clause

Tags: jquery, sql, coldfusion, datatables

Ok so I am currently populating my datatable just fine with coldfusion and everything sorts perfectly. One of the columns in my SQL is the status. Currently I am returning all results WHERE status != 'Completed'

This has worked fine for now, but what I would really like to do is place a checkbox on the page just above the datatable and when checked it would show all records including those that are completed.

Question is, can I do some kind of callback on the check box to dynamically omit the where clause, or do I deliver ALL records to datatables and filter it there? My only worry with that is when the database gets large, returning all records may take a while and 90% of the time they will be filtered out.

Either way, code snippets would be very helpful!

Thanks

Comment: My only advice to you right now is to follow your own advice: "code snippets would be very helpful!" Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: You should be paging your data on the database and only returning X # of rows at a time. Add a .click() event to your checkbox that will re-fire your original .ajax() call passing along the value of the checkbox.

Comment: Brian, you should put your solution as an answer, then you can mark this question as solved. (It is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions on Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### RESOLVED

iKnowKungFoo was right. Since I am using pagination in `datatables`, the query is limited to those rows anyway, eliminating the worry for the large return result.
I implemented the following code to put a `jqueryui` toggle button.

js

```
$('#completed_button').bind('change', function(){
   if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Hide Completed');
      oTable.fnFilter('Completed',6,false);
   } else {
      $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Show Completed');
      oTable.fnFilter('',6,false);
   }
});
```

html

```
<input class="toggle-button" id="completed_button" type="checkbox"  /><label for="completed_button">Show Completed</label>
```

SQL

```
WHERE 1 =1 
<cfif trim(url.sSearch_6) NEQ "Completed">
   AND TS.tickets_status_id != <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="13" />
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the approach depends on the amount of data you're anticipating.  If the checkbox will only filter or include a small number of records, include them in the data return and filter them on the client side.  If that checkbox will have a large impact on the result set, re-firing the data call when the checkbox is changed and filtering on the server is probably a better approach.